# Regex para pegar palavra entre duas palavras ou "/"

Tags: javascript, regex, expressões

Alguém pode me ajudar, gostaria de pegar apenas a palavra entre resourceGroups e providers e atribuir a uma variavel em javascript.

```
/9c2a1079-35f0-4298-9eb3-7f63903f2ae1/resourceGroups/pegarEssaPalavra/providers/
```

Comment: Mas é sempre o penultimo ? Ou é sempre o que está entre as palavras `resourceGroups` e `providers` ?

Comment: I ae Brother... seria sempre o que está entre resourceGroups e providers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essa regex `/\/resourceGroups\/(.*)\/providers\//` pegará o que está entre `/resourceGroups/` e `/providers/` por meio de um grupo.

## Funcionando

```js
let texto = `/9c2a1079-35f0-4298-9eb3-7f63903f2ae1/resourceGroups/pegarEssaPalavra/providers/`

const expressao = /\/resourceGroups\/(.*)\/providers\//

console.log(texto.match(expressao)[1]);
```

Comment: Vlw meu brother... deu certo só fiz uma pequena alteração no Regex para pegar tudo após o provider, porque tem mais itens após eu simplifiquei a uri

Comment: /.*resourceGroups\/|\/providers.*/

Comment: @FernandoAntunes bacana, bom demais ter conseguido.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode tentar algo como:

```
var caminho = "/9c2a1079-35f0-4298-9eb3-7f63903f2ae1/resourceGroups/perarEssaPalavra/providers/";
var separado = path.split('/');
var palavra = split[split.indexOf("resourceGroups") + 1];
```

A palavra que busca estará na variável `palavra`.

Porém, da forma que fiz, obrigatoriamente, a palavra que está buscando deve ficar sempre após a palavra `resourceGroups` no seu `path`.

Isso porque com o `split`, eu separo o seu caminho pelas `/` e depois busco o índice em que a palavra `resourceGroups` está e adiciono mais 1, resultando na palavra que busca.

Answer (score 1):

Pode usar uma regex com `.split()` depois converter a array em string com `.join()`:

```js
var string = "/9c2a1079-35f0-4298-9eb3-7f63903f2ae1/resourceGroups/perarEssaPalavra/providers/";
var resultado = string.split(/.*resourceGroups\/|\/providers\//).join('');

console.log(resultado);
```

Explicação:

A regex `.*resourceGroups\/|\/providers\/` vai quebrar a string em tudo que vier antes até `resourceGroups/` ou a partir de `/providers/`, isolando a palavra `perarEssaPalavra`. Porém a array resultante desse `split` possuirá valores vazios:

```
["", "perarEssaPalavra", ""]
```

Com `.join('')` eu converto a array para string ignorando o que for vazio, resultando em `perarEssaPalavra`.

### Usando `indexOf()` com `substring()`:

Outra forma sem uso de expressões regulares é o simples `.indexOf()` dentro de um `.substring()`:

```js
var string = "/9c2a1079-35f0-4298-9eb3-7f63903f2ae1/resourceGroups/perarEssaPalavra/providers/";
var resultado = string.substring(string.indexOf("resourceGroups/")+15, string.indexOf("/providers"));

console.log(resultado);
```

Como a string `resourceGroups/` tem tamanho fixo, basta pegar a sua posição na string e somar `+15` (referente ao tamanho da string) até a posição da string `/providers`.

Comment: Vlw Dvd... consegui, apenas uma pequena modificação no Regex para pegar tudo apos a palavra Provider.

Comment: var resourceUri = consumos[1].instanceData.resourceUri;
        console.log(resourceUri);

        var resultado = resourceUri.split(/.*resourceGroups\/|\/providers.*/).join('');
        console.log(resultado);

Answer (score 0):

Um regex para isso pode ser da seguinte forma:

```
.*\/([^/]+)\/[^/]+
```

Sendo que nesse caso ele sempre pegará o penúltimo grupo entre as barras, se adicionar 'teste/' ao final, a expressão retornará 'providers'.

Em javascript:

```
const regex = /.*\/([^/]+)\/[^/]+/;
const str = `/9c2a1079-35f0-4298-9eb3-7f63903f2ae1/resourceGroups/cte/pegarEssaPalavra/providers`;
let m;

if ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Veja o exemplo aqui:
https://regex101.com/r/v60aQS/1